# Min and max length of a d3.js graph links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to make a graph simulation with d3 where I can drag the nodes and move them around, but the length of the links must not be less than 300 or more than 600, how can I approach this?

Here is my simulation:

```
const simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation(nodes)
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-300))
  .force(
    "link",
    d3
      .forceLink(links)
      .id((d) => d.id)
      .distance(300),
  )
  .force(
    "center",
    d3.forceCenter(
      container.node().clientWidth / 2 - 75,
      container.node().clientHeight / 2 - 75,
    ),
  );
```

For now I could only set the constat length of a link.

I tried to search in the d3 documentation, but didn't find anything, if there is alerady such a problem with described solution, I would be glad to see it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll have to implement your own force since none of the built-in forces support your use case. For example, forceLink.distance() only initializes the distances once.

A custom implementation would look something like this (see [live demo](https://observablehq.com/d/f2a2ac00edb40559)):

```js
function linkForce(links, {
  min = 50, max = 200, strength = .5, id = d => d.id
} = {}) {
  const clamp = (a, b, v) => v <= a ? a : v >= b ? b : v;
  
  const update = (alpha) => {
    const s = .5 * alpha * strength;
    for(const {source: a, target: b} of links) {
      const dx = a.x + a.vx - b.x - b.vy;
      const dy = a.y + a.vy - b.y - b.vy;
      const dn = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
      const dc = clamp(min, max, dn);
      if(dn === dc) continue;
      const f = (dc - dn) / dn * .5 * alpha * strength;
      a.vx += dx * f;
      a.vy += dy * f;
      b.vx -= dx * f;
      b.vy -= dy * f;
    }
  };

  const initialize = nodes => {
    const map = new Map(nodes.map(d => [id(d), d]));
    for(const link of links) {
      link.source = map.get(link.source);
      link.target = map.get(link.target);
    }
  };
  
  return Object.assign(update, {initialize});
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Btw, can I combine it with forceManyBody to add the initial positions of the nodes? Because now, if I add this, then the logic breaks, I only need the positioning at the begining so I think it's possible. Thank you!

Comment: You can run the simulation [for multiple iterations](https://d3js.org/d3-force/simulation#simulation_tick) and then [remove the force](https://d3js.org/d3-force/simulation#simulation_force).